# Should I throw std::bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, exceptions

I am allocating memory on the stack, and distributing it manually to shared pointers. I end up doing something like this at startup (I've simplified it by ignoring alignment issues):

```
char pool[100];

std::shared_ptr<Obj> p = new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(pool)) Obj;
pool += sizeof(pool);
```

Of course, it is possible that the `100` is not enough, so in that case I'd like to throw an exception:

```
char pool[100];
char* poolLimit = pool + 100;

if (pool + sizeof(Obj) >= poolLimit)
  throw std::bad_alloc(); // is this a good idea?

std::shared_ptr<Obj> p = new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(pool)) Obj;
pool += sizeof(pool);
```

Is it *correct* to throw a `std::bad_alloc` here? Or should I just throw `std::runtime_error`?

Comment: Um...you know that doing that with something on the stack is a disastrously bad idea, right?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Looks like an x/y problem.

Comment: @Ben it's part of an implementation of a heterogenous memory pool. The actual implementation uses `std::align` but for the purpose of this question that kind of detail wasn't necessary. The fact that it allocates on the stack is a minor detail, it could be on the heap as well.

Comment: There is a third option: static memory.  Using `shared_ptr` on something that the system can deallocate itself (when the stack frame goes away) is just asking for trouble.  Even if this is done in `main`, you're still better off using something other than the stack as stacks are often limited in size.  If your goal is to have a large memory pool used for the lifetime of the program, static memory is a far better idea as it never goes away until the program quits and it can usually be of arbitrarily large size (depending on physical RAM/disk.)

Answer (score 3):

(I'm assuming you are writing an user-mode application here, not a kernel module, device driver or network stack).

Throw `std::bad_alloc`. Only an idiot would try to catch that.

But it doesn't *really* matter what you throw because the application is dead at that point anyway. What you want is for the application to quit at that point in a clear and unambiguous way. Calling `abort` would be even better.

If you are operating out of a fixed buffer you really need to make sure it is big enough for all needs.